# Mcrypt error in magento installation

Tags: php, apache, magento

I am installing `Magento 1.9.2` on OS X . php version = 5.38 , I am getting below error:

PHP extension "mcrypt" must be loaded.

I have done `brew install homebrew/php/php55-mcrypt` & then set up the path in `php.ini` like

```
extension_dir=/usr/local/Cellar/php55-mcrypt/5.5.38/
extension=mcrypt.so
```

& then restarted the server. Still I am facing the same error while magento installation.

Comment: CLI PHP and Apache (?) can use different php.ini files. Check a `phpinfo()` output from your browser in a test file somewhere to see if it's installed correctly, don't rely on the CLI output

Answer (score 0):

The problem is related with the way PHP is executed, here is a suggestion (though is linked to MAgento 2 I think can be applied also in your case):

http://osmage.com/magento2/magento-2-installation-composer-setup-sample-data/

Just go in command line and execute:

```
which php
```

And then if from the previous line you don't get a clear understanding of the PHP.ini that is been used you could run the following command:

```
php -i | grep ini
```

Which definitely will return you the php.ini